# How to change time format in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have txt files with Date and Time two different columns.
Current Time format is **02:12:00** (HH:MM:SS)

I want to change above format to **021259** (change SS(00) to 59 as well)

Answer (score 0):

If possible times convert values to strings and then use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `$` for end of strings - replace seconds and also `:` to empty string:

```
print (df)
       Time
0  02:12:00
1  02:12:10

df["Time"] = df["Time"].astype(str).replace({'00$':'59', ':':''}, regex=True)
print (df)
     Time
0  021259
1  021210
```

Answer (score 0):

After some search I found the solution

```
df['Time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.strftime('%H%M'+'59')
```